# Ionic 3 Uncaught (in promise) : plugin_not_installed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem my fingerprint project does not work for me, it generates this error plugin_not_installed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiYU1.jpg)

Well friends any doubt I will be waiting for your answers for hours trying to solve my problem, thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

It seems the plugin you are using in that view is not installed as a cordova plugin. You may have it installed as an npm module but not as a plugin in the platform.
Verify this with:

```
ionic cordova plugin ls
```

The plugin may be not correctly installed in the platform, in this case in iOS. Each platform folder has a plugin folder. Ensure your plugin is inside that folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may have set your FCM in your constructor as private, just replace (private fcm: FCM) with (public fcm: FCM )
then save it , I hope it may solve your problem.